# Google search near location feature

Tags: api, search

I have a question for you, I'm creating myself a simple tool that will check results for some phrases in few languages, and I have it almost ready but, can't deal with one thing, I need to know how to set location by URL or something like that, so that when i check I could check results for ex. for whole germany as well as for berlin etc, you know, I'm talking about a way to set Search Tools > Search Near... feature through automated way, is it possible, by some API, maybe?

Comment: https://moz.com/ugc/the-ultimate-guide-to-the-google-search-parameters